# 1004 not available in a shared workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro which moves cells from the selection to the right (by 5 five cells). It works fine until I share the workbook, is there any simple workaround?

```
Sub dodaj_akcje()
'
' dodaj_akcje Macro
'

'
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("C1:F1").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("c1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Columns("I:M").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you comment kind of answered your own question. If it is not possible in a shared workbook, it is not possible in a shared workbook. Not manually and not from VBA. Can't you unshare the workbook from the macro, run the code, then share it again?

Answer (score 0):

Blind shot but I assume there are some requirements to keep sheets "transactional". 
At the beginning of your macro try: `Sheets("Sheet1").Protect` and at the end `Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect`.

Comment: I am afraid it won't help much. If something is not available when workbook is shared, it is still not executable via macro. I need a workaround to select 30 cells in one row (counting right from selected one) and move them 5 cells to the right.